# How to fix override ToString method

Tags: c#

I am setting up a class with a GUI and having issues on this mandatory ToString method I need in my code. I missed 2 classes due to traveling for a family emergency and now just a little lost on what exactly I am doing here.

Honestly, I don't understand much of whats going on, so I am looking for an explanation. But I have tried watching videos and moving around the code to no avail.

```
class Sandwich
{
    public string name = "Tony";
    public string meat = "None";
    public int tomatoSlices = 1;

    public override tomatoSlices.ToString()
        {
       public double ComputerPrice()
        {
              return 4.0 + (0.5 * tomatoSlices);
        }
    }
}
```

The program should run, but not sure why it isnt. It has something to do with the tomatoSlices integer, I suppose.

Comment: You have a method nested inside another method. Probably move `ComputerPrice` out of `ToString`, and then implement what you want for `ToString`. Also, you don't specify `tomatoSlices` as part of the method name - when you override a base class method, you just use the base class method name, which is `ToString`. You also have to declare a return type of `string` for the method.

Comment: Also, when working with currency, you should use a `decimal` datatype rather than a `double` to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: Is this what you want? `public override string ToString() { return (4.0 + (0.5 * tomatoSlices)).ToString(); }`

Comment: ITs not currency, its literally the amount of tomato slices you want on the sandwich

Comment: @CrazeSchwazey I guess I was confused by the word `Price` in the method name, and the fact that it's a different value than the `int tomatoSlices`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you have declared a method inside another method. You need to move the `ComputerPrice()` outside of the `ToString` method. Also, you need to remove the `tomatoSlices` from the `ToString` definition:

```
class Sandwich
{
    public string name = "Tony";
    public string meat = "None";
    public int tomatoSlices = 1;

    public double ComputerPrice()
    {
         return 4.0 + (0.5 * tomatoSlices);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ComputerPrice().ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, when you call `sandwich.ToString()` it will return the value of `ComputerPrices()` as a string e.g.:

```
var sandwich = new Sandwich();

var price = sandwich.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you! but still having errors. The teacher wants it like this. -Inside of the Sandwich class, create constructor with no parameters. Initialize the properties as follows: -Name should be assigned “Tony” o Meat should be assigned “None” -TomatoSlices should be assigned 1 -Inside of the Sandwich class, create the ToString method with the following method header: public override string ToString() -Right under the ToString method, type in the following ComputePrice method

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what you want, but you have a method nested inside another method, which is not legal.

Probably you want to move `ComputerPrice()` out of the `ToString()` method, and then implement what you want for `ToString()` (which is typically the string representation of the class).

Also, you don't specify `tomatoSlices` as part of the method name; when you override a base class method, you just use the base class method name, which is `ToString()`. You also have to declare a return type of `string` for the method.

Other things you may want to do are:

1. Use public properties instead of fields
2. Use PascalCase for public members
3. Use the `decimal` datatype for working with currency (to avoid rounding errors)

Here's a sample class that addresses all these issues:

```
class Sandwich
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Meat { get; set; }
    public int TomatoSlices { get; set; }

    public Sandwich()
    {
        Name = "Tony";
        Meat = "None";
        TomatoSlices = 1;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"This sandwich named {Name} " +
               $"has {Meat} meat and {TomatoSlices} slices of " +
               $"tomato, for a total cost of {ComputerPrice()}";

         // Or just return the price if that's what you want instead:
         // return ComputerPrice().ToString();
    }

    public decimal ComputerPrice()
    {
        return 4M + 0.5M * TomatoSlices;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the homework prompt, its not that complex- I'm just dumb lol.
-Inside of the Sandwich class, create constructor with no parameters. Initialize the properties as follows:
-Name should be assigned “Tony”
o Meat should be assigned “None”
-TomatoSlices should be assigned 1
-Inside of the Sandwich class, create the ToString method with the following method header:
     public override string ToString()
-Right under the ToString method, type in the following ComputePrice method

Comment: Well, add a constructor and set the default property values there, and move `ComputerPrice` below `ToString` then? Your comment is not what you asked about in the question.